# Moose horn from Sweden to UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, luggage

Am I able to bring a moose skull with horns in my luggage from Sweden to the UK?

Comment: Is it clean? Can you prove that it is from Sweden?

Comment: It's a gift from a friend who is a hunter but there is no proof other than the fact I'm flighing from Sweden. It's dry bone, no skin or flesh but it hasn't been treated or anything

Comment: How large is it? Unless Swedish moose are much, much smaller than the North American ones I'm familiar with, it won't fit in luggage. You'll have to make special arrangements, just to accommodate for the size (to say nothing of importing animal products).

Comment: Too big to fit in a large suitcase but contacted the airline and they said it's fine just wrap it up and buy more luggage. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 2):

Legally? As long as it is "personal" then it's fine:

From [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/personal-food-plant-and-animal-product-imports)

> From EU countries: You can bring any fruit, vegetables, meat, dairy or other animal products (eg fish, eggs and honey) into the UK if you’re travelling from a country within the EU.

While it doesn't explicitly mention hunting trophies, the fact that animal products are broadly permitted should cover you.